# Using FindBugs with Play Framework 2

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt, findbugs

I'd like to integrate FindBugs into the build process of a Play Framework 2 Java project.

Is this possible? If so, what are the configuration steps required to make it work?

I'm assuming it's possible to use [findbugs4sbt](https://bitbucket.org/jmhofer/findbugs4sbt/wiki/Home), but I'm unsure about how to set it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just did this yesterday and documented it in [Integrating Findbugs Into a Play Framework 2 Project (Java)](http://inoio.de/blog/2013/01/08/integrating-findbugs-into-a-playframework-2-project-java/).

This are the relevant steps:

1. <s>Download my custom build of [findbugs4sbt jar for sbt 0.11 from bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/magro/findbugs4sbt/downloads/findbugs4sbt_2.9.1_0.11.3-1.1.7.jar) and put it into `project/lib`</s>

   **Update:** Add the plugin in `project/plugins.sbt` via

   ```scala
   addSbtPlugin("de.johoop" % "findbugs4sbt" % "1.1.7")
   ```
2. Configure findbugs4sbt in `project/Build.scala`:

   ```scala
   import de.johoop.findbugs4sbt.FindBugs._

   object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

     ...

     val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = JAVA,
       settings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ findbugsSettings)

   }
   ```

Then you can already run `sbt findbugs` which generates `target/scala-2.9.1/findbugs/findbugs.xml`.

As findbugs also analyzes some classes compiled by play from routes and views (and reports some issues regarding naming conventions), you probably want to ignore them (as you can't improve them anyways). To do this exclude them from findbugs with the following findbugs4sbt settings (in `project/Build.scala`):

```scala
val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = JAVA,
settings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ findbugsSettings).settings(
  findbugsExcludeFilters := Some(
    <FindBugsFilter>
      <!-- See docs/examples at http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/filter.html -->
      <Match>
        <Class name="~views\.html\..*"/>
      </Match>
      <Match>
        <Class name="~Routes.*"/>
      </Match>
      <Match>
        <Class name="~controllers\.routes.*"/>
      </Match>
    </FindBugsFilter>
  )
)
```

Comment: Thank you, works fine. I noticed that your changes got merged into findbugs4sbt so I just added the plugin to plugins.sbt directly using _addSbtPlugin("de.johoop" % "findbugs4sbt" % "1.1.7")_

Comment: Thanx for remembering me :-), I updated this answer accordingly.

Comment: Note that this code needs a few updates to work with Play 2.2.

Comment: Most setups instruction changed now. Refer to the github repo for updated information.